# How can I weigh columns in data frame and add them up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 5 columns, I only want to add the second and the third, but each point in the third column has to be **multiplied by 3**,
 so I need to add a new column called 
`"Total score" which is df['Second'] + 3* df['Third']`

I have tried with sum but I don't know how to indicate that I want weigh and select only two columns

Comment: please post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your columns is order correctly, then we can using `dot`

```
df['Total Score'] = df.dot([0,1,3,0,0])
```

Or to be safe

```
df['Total Score'] = df[['Second','Third']].dot([1,3])
```

Comment: I always get this error "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: @NellyLouis that is set copy error , so you may want to check with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas